# Install zImage on Android 2.2 devcie

Tags: kernel, fastboot

How do I install zImage on Android 2.2 device? I have one galaxy tab 7.0 and one NVIDIA Tegra 250 delvel kit.

I was trying to using fastboot on NVIDIA Tegra 250 but I failed.

I could load zImage using following command

```
fastboot boot zImage
```

The device shows that it downloaded the image but nothing happened. If I forced to restart then the kernel wasn't updated.

As for the Gallaxy Tab, I was trying to load the zImage with odin. But the input format should be either .tar or something else not the zImage.

I have been trying to figure this out for two weeks and I am still stuck. 
I will be very appreciated if you guys could help with that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think you might be able to flash it directly to the device with `fastboot flash zimage /path/to/zImage`. I don't have a means of testing this at the moment, but you could give that a try.

Comment: I've attempted to answer but could you provide more information on what source you're using for this kernel and how you're producing it?  (We can't help you with the dev side, but the info may help us tell you why the flashing isn't working.)

Answer (score 2):

The Odin-able kernels for my Galaxy S are simply the zImage in a .tar file.  But the zImage has a peculiar format, and I believe it's specific to Samsung devices.

I would assume that either the kernel you've compiled is the wrong format, or simply doesn't work and the system is restoring the stock kernel from the recovery image.

Answer (score 0):

```
fastboot boot zImage
```

is for testing purpose only. It will boot your phone to the kernel for only once. The next time you boot your phone, it will use the original kernel.